# MVC View designer complains "There is no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate edition) Update 2.  I'm not sure if this problem is related to that update but.. now, when I view any of my View (.aspx) code in the VS designer, the initial `@model` or `@using` directive gets a squiggly underline and an associated error message of "There is no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/xxx".  All of the code in the page that relies on the `@model` or `@using` directive gets its own associated squiggly underline errors.  But the code runs just fine.  The error is in the designer, not in the runtime JIT compiler magic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit more digging, I found [a blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/be50be61-39eb-49ba-aaf5-b18ded17c107/) that suggested that the problem might be caused by failing to run VS as administrator.  I tried that (I ran VS as administrator and loaded the offending solution) and, bada bing, bada boom, problem solved.

I've been happily skipping the "run as administrator" rigmarole for ASP.NET projects, and everything has worked correctly.  I guess they must have changed something in Update 2 that now requires ASP.NET MVC projects to be opened with admin privs.

**Can someone who knows better than I confirm this diagnosis?**

(BTW, I ran across [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhiann/archive/2013/02/14/always-run-visual-studio-2012-as-administrator-in-windows-8.aspx) that shows how to force VS to always run with admin privs on Windows 8.  This is an all-or-nothing solution...  What I'd REALLY like is for the VS developers - or someone with time on their hands - to add a context menu item to .sln files to open them in VS with admin privs enabled.)

EDIT:

4 months after I posted this "solution" (actually, a work-around), here's where I am:  I opened an incident with MSDN tech support.  After much work, we got nowhere; still no clue what the underlying problem might be.  But this problem only exists on my desktop PC - my laptop doesn't have the problem - and I'm buying a new PC, so the problem should go away when I install VS on the new PC and turn the old PC into a doorstop.